# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build XXX status: FAILURE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my application howvever i recieve this error:

```html
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ce067810-d3ad-4ebe-b8ba-b9fa03e371a4 status: FAILURE
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@8.12.0 does not satisfy ajv@6.12.6
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global]
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
```

running npm ci does not seem to change and i am running on node v 16.13.0

I am not sure what the error means, any help would be appreciated

app.yaml:

```js
runtime: nodejs18
service: default
entrypoint: serve -s build
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "stripe": "^12.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Include the contents of your ```app.yaml``` file

Comment: Did you include `package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json`? Delete them.

Comment: deleting them and rebuilding does not work.

Comment: If you deleted those files, you would not have an error message about them. `lock file's ajv@8.12.0 does not satisfy ajv@6.12.6`

Comment: I still received an out of sync error and missing typescript error.

Answer (score 1):

The lock file (`package-lock.json`), which is relevant to the problem you're seeing, is not in sync with the `package.json` file. The lock file is used to guarantee reliable and consistent installation of dependencies.

Before deploying your application, you must execute `npm install` to update the lock file in order to fix the deployment error.

This command will update the lock file to ensure compatibility between dependencies and install the dependencies listed in your `package.json` file. You can then attempt to deploy your application once more.